# HTML and JavaScript App

Tags: javascript, android, html

I want to make an app with HTML and Javascript. I am not master at these. So I need a bit of help. The image of the app

[image]

Now what I want is when I will click on any place inside orange area the number in middle will increase by 1. How can I do that using javascript. My code is given below:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Tabjih</title>
  <style>
    html,
    body,
    .container {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .container {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      background-color: orange;
    }
    p {
      font-size: 200px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <p id="text">0</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Please suggest me javascript code needed to add to this to achieve wht i want.

Comment: Try this link it will help you.. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076679/javascript-event-registering-without-using-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Bind `click` event listener on the `container` element using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
2. Get the current value from the `text` element
3. Cast the value to `integer` using [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)
4. Increment the value by one
5. Update the value in `text` element

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.getElementById('container').addEventListener('click', function() {

    // Get the current value from the element
    var value = parseInt(this.innerText, 10) || 0;

    // increment the value by one, and update it in DOM
    document.getElementById('text').innerText = ++value;

    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body,
.container {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: orange;
}
p {
  font-size: 200px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Tabjih</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container" class="container">
    <p id="text">0</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is really the best answer I found with steps cleared. Thanks @Tushar. But can you help me one more time? Actually I am not much literate in HTML and so so. When I click the orange area it increases but sometimes the text is being selected. How can I stop this thing?

Comment: @AbeerHussain You cannot, this is default behavior of browsers. You can at least use `return false` in the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0].addEventListener("click",function(){

document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById('text').innerHTML)+1;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s6qc2w3g/12/