# Displaying form values on clicking submit without using "onsubmit"

Tags: javascript, html, forms

This is the simple html code, with the script I have :

```js
var v1 = document.getElementByID("goo");
window.alert(v1[0].value + " " + v1[1].value);
```

```html
<html>
<form id="goo">
  <input type="text" id="one">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

</html>
```

I want to display the form values when the user clicks submit. One way of doing it would be to make the script a function ( say `function f1()` ) and then modify the form tag as:

```
<form id="goo" onsubmit="f1()">
```

However, is there a way to do it without modifying the html code and using only Javascript?

Why would I want to do it? I'm new to this and I'm just curious.

Comment: ...but the answers there are not good. I'll post a better one (well, better to *my* eyes, anyway).

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know the terms and hence had not searched well before posting I guess.

Comment: Which means your question may be found by other people, who will then go see the answer. Result. :-)

Comment: [Answered that question now](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33963475/157247).