# Javascript - Can I run my event handler AFTER the default handler for the "onkeypress" event?

Tags: javascript

I have an input text and I want to run my function after the default event handler

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="myfunction()"></input>
```

the function

```
function myfunction(){alert($("input")[0].value)}
```

because `myfunction()` is using the input `value` and this property will be changed after the default handler runs and change it.
Example: if the text field has value "1234" , and I pressed the key "5", the function will alert "1234" not "12345"

So, I want the default function runs first to change the `value` property , then I can use it in `myfunction()`

**can I do something like this ?!**

```
 onkeypress="default();myfunction()"
```

I did a work around by putting `myfunction()` in the **`onkeyup`** event, but I don't want that.

*Thanks, and please consider I'm very newbie.*

Comment: Use `keyup/input` event for that..

Comment: @Rayon oninput worked exactly as I want , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TRIVIAL SOLUTION:**

You should use `oninput` instead of `onkeypress`. Like so:

`<input type="text" oninput="myfunction(event)" />`

The [`keypress`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress) event is emitted when a key gets pressed, i.e., *before* the DOM is modified with the pressed key's value. This is why you never got the value of the last key pressed.

The [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event is emitted when data is entered into the `input` element. So we can access the data by reading the value of the element.

---

**USING EVENT-BINDING:**

1. HTML

`<input id="input_field" type="text" />`

2. jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#input_field").on("input", function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
  });
});
```

3. Pure JS

```
    var input_field = document.getElementById("input_field");
    input_field.addEventListener("input", function(event) {
        console.log(event.target.value);
    });
```

**NOTE:** Add this in a script tag *after* the HTML or use `window.onload` to simulate the behaviour of `$(document).ready`.

See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33963475/3507137) for more information about how event-binding works.

Comment: Though it will work, consider support for `input` event. Also it is better to use `JavaScript-Event-Binding` than `Inline-Event-Binding`

Comment: `oninput` did what I want , thanks . just for curiosity , can't I change the order of the default handler to make it run first?

Comment: @Rayon I'll add it to my answer